# Can multi mongos support to insert data concurrently in sharded cluster

Tags: mongodb, cluster-computing

I deployed a Mongodb sharded cluster with 3 mongos, 3 config servers and 3 shard servers.

To insert data to mongodb fastly, I split a big file(3 million documents) to 3 smaller files, then insert a smaller file(about 1 million documnets) to a mongos separately, eg: (file A vs monos A, file B vs monos B, file C vs mongo C).

After inserting, I ensured shard key, enabled sharding and sharded collection.  when I queried the count of documents. I got a number, which was not equal I ever inserted. I can not explain the reason. who knows ? Thank you so much.